# Can I set the process title for IIS6's w3wp.exe?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis-6, w3wp

In Visual Studio's "Attach to Process" dialog I can see a Title column for each of the processes available. Is there any way for me to set the title for a specific w3wp.exe process to reflect the application pool it's hosting?

PS - I'm aware of iisapp.vbs and the way it enables me to identify which w3wp.exe belongs to which application pool. I'm aiming for a more user-friendly solution here :)

PPS - Currently running IIS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are debugging on non production servers, the easiest thing to do is to set the identities of each w3wp process to different accounts.  I cannot find anything in IIS admin to set the title.  Even when the debugger is running I cannot set the title like I can in threads.  Hope this helps.